# Check if SQL Server 2005 XML field is empty

Tags: sql-server, xml-column, is-empty

I just did this:

```
Delete FROM MyTable WHERE ScopeValue = "" 
Delete FROM G_Scope WHERE ScopeValue is ''
Delete FROM G_Scope WHERE ScopeValue = empty
Delete FROM G_Scope WHERE ScopeValue is empty
```

I want to delete all rows with xml field (not nullable) where ScopeValue column has empty entries means zero chars.

Anyone knows?

Answer (score 13):

Try this:

```
 DELETE FROM dbo.G_Scope WHERE ScopeValue IS NULL
```

The SQL Server column would be `NULL` is if contains no value.

The other possibility would be that the XML is not NULL, but contains an empty string as its value. For that, use this command:

```
-- The DATALENGTH of an empty XML column is 5
SELECT * FROM dbo.G_Scope WHERE DATALENGTH(ScopeValue) = 5
```

Does that show you the rows you're interested in?

Comment: thats odd..., either I did this before Is NULL... and it seems I have a sql studio management display refresh problem.

I can do selects on the table again and again its showing ScopeValues with empty fields...

Comment: @marc_s I believe the datalength of an empty XML var would be 5: `declare @x xml;
set @x='';
select datalength(@x);
select cast(@x as varbinary(max))`